# How do you store a reference to a property in C#?

Tags: c#, reference, properties

I'm creating a game, and am currently working on the Inventory system for it. I have a class to represent the player, which looks like this:

```
class Player {
    public Weapon WeaponSlot {get;set;}
    public Shield ShieldSlot {get;set;}
    //etc.
}
```

Weapon, Shield, etc are subclasses of a generic Item class:

```
class Item {
    //...
}

class Weapon : Item {
    //...
}
```

There are subclasses of Weapon, etc, but that's not important.

Anyway, I am creating a UserControl to display/modify the contents of a given inventory slot. However, I'm not sure exactly how to do that. In C++, I would use something like:

```
new InventorySlot(&(player.WeaponSlot));
```

But, I can't do that in C#.

I found the TypedReference struct, but that doesn't work since you are not allowed to make a field with one of those structs, so I couldn't store it for use later in the control.

Is reflection the only way to go, or is there some other facility that I'm not aware of?

EDIT ----

For reference, here's what I've done:

```
partial class InventorySlot : UserControl {
    PropertyInfo slot;
    object target;

    public InventorySlot(object target, string field) {

        slot = target.GetType().GetProperty(field);

        if (!slot.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Item)) && !slot.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(Item))) throw new //omitted for berevity

        this.target = target;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //...
}
```

And, it's initialized like this:

```
new InventorySlot(player, "WeaponSlot");
```

Also, regarding performance, I'm not too concerned about that. It's not a real-time game, so I only have to update the screen in response to player actions. :)

Comment: Just to clarify, I have two requirements:

1. The object whose properties I want to modify has several properties whose names are not known to the control

2. There may be more than one such object of different classes I want to modify.

As such, I cannot just store a reference to the object, since I cannot divine its type at runtime.

So far, I'm using reflection, which appears to be the way to go.

Comment: reading your comment the fact you aren't aware of what you need to do fully except at runtime leaves your sole choice to be reflection. Since this is a game you will want to make sure you aggressively cache your reflection calls (I'd recommend looking at a static readonly ConcurrentDictionary or even persisting this data to disk or perhaps a document database etc).

Comment: Performance is not an issue in this case. If it was, I wouldn't be using WinForms :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially what you are creating is a property browser. Have a look at Windows Forms' [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx) control (read the docs to see how it works and/or use Reflector to read the code).

The short answer is to simply use reflection. By storing a PropertyDescriptor you can get and set the value of the property member given the object instance.

Comment: Sounds like this is the way to go... I thought there might be another way, but thanks

Comment: It really is the way to go. Not only do you gain access to the property value, but also to any metadata it might have (i.e. Attributes).

Answer (score 4):

> I am creating a UserControl to
>   display/modify the contents of a given
>   inventory slot. However, I'm not sure
>   exactly how to do that. In C++, I
>   would use something like

It works the way you want by default. "ref" keyword is not needed either.

Comment: The problem is that the inventory slots are properties on an object, not objects themselves. I need(ed) a reference to the property itself, which is only possible with reflection. (which is the route I went)

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior afaik

Answer (score 0):

Every `class` type object is a reference in c#.   Value types are declared with `struct`.

So for example:

```
Weapon w1 = new Weapon();
w2 = w1;//Does not make a copy just makes a second reference to what w1 is pointing to
```

If you need an input/output parameter to a function you can use `ref`.  If you need an output parameter you can use `out`.  If you are just passing a reference to an object that is of type `class` then you can just pass it and modify the class object itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could clone the object to achieve what you want:

```
public class Weapon : ICloneable
{
    public string Name;

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return this.Clone();
    }
    public Weapon Clone()
    {
        return (Weapon)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

You can than do something like this to get a copy of that object with all the internal values:

```
Weapon w1 = new Weapon();
Weapon w2 = w1.Clone()
```

Comment: Scrap this.. :) This is how you could do it if you did not want to modify the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a reference, you can use fields instead. They can be referenced by `ref`.

Comment: And, how would I STORE this reference for later consumption?